# How do you set Json.Net Schema to have stricter validation of commas, new lines etc

Tags: c#, json, validation, json.net, jsonschema

Json.Net is very forgiving of the json it parses. It will for example deal with un-escaped newline characters in a string, and will not be phased by a trailing commas in an array. E.g.,:

```
"[{\"coffee\":\withsugar\"},]"     //trailing comma
"[{\"coffee\":\"with\r\nsugar\"}]" //un-escaped newline
```

This is a very good thing when parsing.

Json.Net Schema also says this json is valid. However the T-SQL [`ISJSON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921896.aspx) function says that it is not. It is also not valid according to http://json.org/

**Is there a way of using Json.Net Schema to strictly validate json against the *json format* (not just json schema)?**

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question, so I'll use a comment, but if you are trying to check if JSON is strictly valid independent of JSON.NET, it would be a fairly easy to write a pass-through TextReader implementation of a state machine that checked the validity of the JSON, and use that with JSON's Deserialize() method to enforce validity as it was being parsed by JSon.Net.

Comment: you may use IsValid and Validate overloads as described here http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm check whatever you would like to check and mark the result as not valid.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey I think that will work for un-escaped newline characters etc. Will work for the trailing commas as well?

Comment: @DarcyThomas I don't have VS open now otherwise I'd have given you a sample that I already have for the same problem.

Comment: @DarcyThomas You can also try to inherit jsonvalidator class and override validate method as shown here http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CustomJsonValidators.htm